# useEffect with asyn function not updating state (or not running again with state change) - Nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get used to async data fetching in react and there's something I'm misunderstanding.

I need to render out a list of recipes from my API, this is the route I fetch that gets me my recipes, it works fine. This is called when fetching
`/api/recipes`

```js
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req){
    const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies });
  let recipes, error;
  try {
    ({data : recipes, error} = await supabase.from('Recipes').select('*'));
    if(error){
      throw error;
    }
    console.log(recipes)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    alert(error.description || error.message);
  }
  return NextResponse.json({recipes})
}
```

Now in my react component, I cant seem to understand how to get my state to update or my useeffect doesnt seem to respond to the fetch calls resolving and setting a new state.

```js
"use client"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function() {

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getRecipes() {
      const res = await fetch("/api/recipes");
      const ress = await res.json();
      setRecipes[ress.recipes];
    }
    getRecipes();

    console.log(recipes)
  }, [recipes])
  
  

  return (
    <div className="font-sans text-3xl">
      {recipes}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I understand that setting state is also async so I wont see the new state in the first console log however I should see it on a second time when the recipes state changes as its in my dependency array.

So either my useeffect isnt running right, or my state isnt even updating.

**btw if I `console.log(ress.recipes)` it returns my recipes, the data/endpoint works fine**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues I'm seeing...

---

This syntax is wrong:

```
setRecipes[ress.recipes];
```

You invoke a function with *parentheses*, not *brackets*:

```
setRecipes(ress.recipes);
```

---

Don't include `recipes` in the dependency array:

```
}, [recipes])
```

Because every time `recipes` changes, the effect will re-run.  And since the effect changes `recipes`, that's an infinite loop.  Use an empty dependency array to execute the effect just once when the component first renders:

```
}, [])
```

---

Remove this:

```
console.log(recipes)
```

It won't show you anything meaningful, since (1) the asynchronous operation hasn't completed yet and (2) even if you await that operation, the state hasn't been updated yet.

---

Aside from that, your next step will simply be to decide how you want to actually display these records.  Just showing the raw array won't be very useful:

```
{recipes}
```

You can iterate over the array and show some markup for each record.  For example:

```
{recipes.map(r => (
  <div>Show information from "r" here.</div>
))}
```

Comment: Oh my god. The syntax. That was it Why did I use square brackets and why didnt it throw an error. Ffs. Ok Im sane again, I'm not as dumb as I thought. Yeah the rest of your pointers are valid and I was aware of them, I was just frantic and trying all kinds of things

Comment: @SaifeldeenAdel Please accept this answer if it helped you. This will help future visitors and raise the poster's some reputation (slightly).